# Error by reading csv dataset numeric-character

Tags: r, rstudio, character, rtweet

When working with the rtweet package in r I got a problem with the type of data, when I want to read the csv with read.csv() and knit the document I got the following error term:
"Column `reply_to_status_id` can't be converted from numeric to character”

I wanted to read a list of files which were in one folder, but only one of them has the problem with the error term and I already identified the one but I don’t know how to solve it.

```
files <- list.files("./documents/", full.names = T)
tidy_tweets<- files %>% map_df(read_csv) %>% bind_rows()
```

I only got this problem for one data set, for the other data sets I never received that issue. It might be because I used another command for saving the data so that it didn’t saved the data as character.
I already tried to solve the problem by using the following term when reading the csv, but it didn’t work.

```
tidy_tweets<- files %>% map_df(read_csv) %>% mutate(reply_to_status_id = as.character(reply_to_status_id) %>% bind_rows() 
mutate(reply_to_status_id = as.character(reply_to_status_id)
```

Does someone have the same issue and know how to solve it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: hello everyone can someone help me?

Comment: did you try the `sep=` option? if your data table does not use the default seperator that could be a problem